# Assembler - indirect memory addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, addressing-mode

i'm a newbie to Assembly , done some Java/C before.. so it's like learning to crawl after flying.

Im currently learning from 'Tutorial's Point' as it seems really begginer friendly.

I've encountered this code:

```
MY_TABLE TIMES 10 DW 0  ; Allocates 10 words (2 bytes) each initialized to 0
MOV EBX, [MY_TABLE]     ; Effective Address of MY_TABLE in EBX
MOV [EBX], 110          ; MY_TABLE[0] = 110
ADD EBX, 2              ; EBX = EBX +2
MOV [EBX], 123          ; MY_TABLE[1] = 123
```

1. Allocating the *effective address* of MY_TABLE to EBX , kinda means like a *pointer* to the table's first value? (i know its not comparable to *C*... but i gotta understand it somehow :))
2. it says ADD EBX , 2 (which means *inc* the EBX register by 2 , but then when reffered to it the next line , shouldn't it reffer to the [2] place? again.. thinking of this like *C*'s Arrays.

hope this question is on the spot. 
I wanna Thank everyone in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`MOV EBX, [MY_TABLE]` will read 4 bytes from the memory at address `MY_TABLE` (ie. first two elements of the "array").

By the comment I would guess the author intended to use `LEA EBX, [MY_TABLE]`.

`LEA` is short for "load effective address", and it is basically the first half of instruction `MOV` with memory reference variant. It will calculate the final address, from where such `MOV` would load data, but instead of contacting memory chip, and loading data, the address itself is loaded into destination register. Also the same can be achieved in NASM by `MOV ebx,MY_TABLE` or in MASM/TASM by `MOV ebx,OFFSET MY_TABLE`.

So yes, it's like pointer to first value in table, but to fully appreciate the rawness of Assembly you should keep in mind, it's like pointer to the first BYTE in the table, as pointers in Assembly don't have any type, in 32b protected mode with flat memory model (Win32, linux32) address is `uint32_t`, and memory is addressable by bytes, so every such number points somewhere into memory (either where physical RAM chip / device I/O is mapped, or into empty invalid region). That's limiting simple flat-memory 32b mode to 4GiB of memory space (x86 allows for more complex memory mapping schemes in 32b modes, which allows to address more than 4GiB of memory address space, but not with single 32b register address of course).

2) as that pointer points at BYTES, and your table is from WORDS, each word is of 2 bytes size. First element of the table is at offset `0`, but does occupy also next byte at offset `1`. First byte of second value (table[1] in C) is at offset `2`. Thus `add ebx,2` is used to get address of second value. `add ebx,1` would made you point into the middle of first `my_table[0]` value.

Try to not refer to these things like their C counterparts, arrays themselves are sort of low level, so it often does match, but any more high level C constructs often just confuse it more. C arrays already hide from you the pointer arithmetic, using the element type to calculate correct address for you. In assembly that doesn't happen.

Other variants how 32b x86 can address C-like value `my_table[1]`:

```
lea  ebx,[my_table]
mov  esi,1
mov  ax,[ebx + esi*2]  ; by index register scaled by 2

lea  ebx,[my_table]
mov  esi,2
mov  ax,[ebx + esi]    ; by offset

lea  ebx,[my_table]
mov  ax,[ebx + 2]      ; by immediate offset

mov  ax,[my_table + 2] ; by absolute address
```

---

Edit: now I did finally notice what you actually do with that `ebx`. I consider `MOV [EBX], 110` "sloppy" programming style, because from neither argument of such `mov` it is clear what is the data size.

If you do `mov [ebx],ax`, the size of `ax` defines the data width of such operation to be 16 bits, but `110` can be 8, 16 or 32 bit immediate (or even 64b in 64b mode). So the proper/nice style in such situation (memory reference vs immediate) is to explicitly specify the argument size, like:

```
mov [ebx], word 110   ; C-like: ((short *)my_table)[some_index] = (short)110;
```

And for performance reasons on modern x86 it is better to avoid using 16 bit parts of registers, so when you are dealing with array of shorts or bytes, it may be better to load them by extending them into full 32 bit value:

```
movzx eax,word [ebx] ; to extend word value [ebx] with zero bits
movsx ecx,byte [esi] ; to sign-extend value [ebx]
    ; the top most (sign) bit of original value is copied up to fill upper ecx
```

Then you can do all your calculations with 32b variant of register (`eax` and `ecx` in the example above), and use the partial `ax` and `cl` only at the end of calculation to store the proper result (of course make sure that the calculation itself is not producing wrong results due to 32 bit register/values usage).

Comment: Better to use `movzx/movsx word ptr eax,[ebx+...]` Try to never use partial registers.

Comment: @Johan why? AFAIK if you use only `ax`, it's not a problem. Performance penalty is paid only when you suddenly start to work with `eax` after partial write.

Comment: @Johan according to this http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf I don't see any reason for that, do you have some data for which architecture that happens? Actually `movzx` used to be slower before PPro, and on AMD CPUs for another decade or so.

Comment: You can see the difference in the instruction tables: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf  On newer architecture like Skylake the 16 bits moves have 2 uops, not 1 and whereas 32+bit moves may be eliminated, 16-bit moves cannot. On Ivy Bridge the CPU can execute 3 `movzx` in parallel, but only 2 `mov r16,[mem]`. Small differences to be sure, but it's good practise to always use the movzx/movsx variants anyway (not so much because of these tiny difference, but because of the (false) dependency when using the full register later.

Comment: @Johan thank you for info. I think for tutorial it is easier to show simple 16 bit code, without explaining why `movzx` + using `eax` for calculation and then why storing just `ax` back into memory in the end. About performance... you may be capped by memory throughput, there's so many free cycles to be used when you have to process large block of memory, that 1 uop difference may be not measurable at all. And if you operate over small data hot in cache, then it's likely there's no need for 16b packing to save memory. But using `movzx` sounds less error-prone, so good to know it is now faster.